# Disable order comments in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have integrated my website with woocommerce. However, everything Woocommerce updates as status is displayed in the wordpress comments, which makes it a hassle to view. Any idea how to create something in functions.php to make it stop displaying them there?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove reviews altogether from products? [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-completely-disable-reviews-tab#post-3957399) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/) might help you)

Answer (score 0):

You could add 'woocommerce' to your comments' black list so they won't show up in the list.